# Jackson JsonMappingException continue and get full raport

Tags: java, json, jackson, mappingexception

I have been looked for solution but found only old or questions without answers.

When i have large model with Jackson @JsonProperty mapping and ObjectMapper, there are many of types of fields, when i'm mapping it with prepared wrong data e.g. in some field String instead of Integer i'm getting JsonMappingException with perfect information of error location etc, but because the model is large i want to return for client full report which fields are bad.

e.g

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;

}
```

and

```
{
    "a" : "foo",
    "b" : "bar"
}
```

In jackson 2.8 release notes i found:

> It is possible that with future versions we may try to add some form
>   of "do not fail on first problem", aggregation of multiple failures,
>   but with 2.8 this is just foundational support for building such
>   support externally.

but i didn't find any information that it is implemented now. What is the best solution for now (external supporting this) of this problem.

Thanks for any help !